# How to prevent iText from overlaping with elements a the bottom of my page

Tags: java, itext, footer, itext7

I have a table in iText that adds elements from my Jtable, but the cells in which i add the information always go to the bottom of the page regardless of how many cells there are, i am using itext version 7.1.16. Here is my code and an image what it looks like

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("/home/user/Desktop/out.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(pdf,PageSize.A4);
PdfFont headFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont cellFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);

Table table1 = new Table(5);
table1.setFixedPosition(0f, 0f, 595);
table1.setHeight(550);

table1.addHeaderCell(new Cell()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
    .add(new Paragraph("Ime"))
    .setFont(headFont));
table1.addHeaderCell(new Cell()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
    .add(new Paragraph("Šifra"))
    .setFont(headFont));
table1.addHeaderCell(new Cell()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
    .add(new Paragraph("Opis"))
    .setFont(headFont));
table1.addHeaderCell(new Cell()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
    .add(new Paragraph("Mjerna Jedinica"))
    .setFont(headFont));
table1.addHeaderCell(new Cell()
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
    .setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
    .add(new Paragraph("Kolicina"))
    .setFont(headFont));

for(int i = 0;i<Table.getRowCount();i++){

    table1.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(ime.toString()))
        .setFont(cellFont)
        .setMinHeight(0));
    table1.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(sif.toString()))
        .setFont(cellFont));
    table1.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(op.toString()))
        .setFont(cellFont));
    table1.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(mj.toString()))
        .setFont(cellFont));
    table1.addCell(new Cell()
        .add(new Paragraph(kol1.toString()))
        .setFont(cellFont));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```java
Table table1 = new Table(5);
table1.setFixedPosition(0f, 0f, 595);
table1.setHeight(550);
```

In your `setFixedPosition` call you explicitly position the table in the lower left corner (`0f, 0f`) and make it as wide as the page (`595`).

So if you don't want the table to *go to the bottom of the page regardless of how many cells there are,* don't position it at the bottom.

In your `setHeight` call you explicitly make the table pretty high (`550`), much higher than required for those few entries.

So if you don't want the cells to be so unnecessary huge, don't make the table that high.

I don't know your use case, there may be a reason why you explicitly set position, width, and height of the table. If there is no such reason, though, don't set those values at all and let iText do the layout.

Comment: Yes but if I don't use setFixedPosition() to set the exact coordinates and with of the table, it sets i in the top right corner. The preferred position i would like it to be at is at that specific height and not to overlap the elements i have at the bottom . On the other hand, if i use setFixedPosition() to set it where i want it, the cells act normally but then the table gets pushed up and off the page, how can i set the table at a specific coordinate but make the rows go towards the bottom  and off the page skipping the elements at the bottom?

Comment: How about `table1.setFixedPosition(0f, 50f, 595);
table1.setHeight(500);`?

Comment: yup with 150f and 400 height it doesn't go over the footer anymore, but up to a certain amount of components the disappear into the void at 150f, is there a way to transfer the elements that go below 150f to the next page?                                                            
And a way to delete the borders cuz they still streach